# ClassNotFoundException - While Loading a Class Dynamically in a Web Application using ClassLoader

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, web, netbeans-7, classnotfoundexception

I am trying to load a class dynamically using loadClass method of java ClassLoader in NetBeans IDE.
When I run the following standalone program it gets executed properly and prints the output as expected:

```
public class StandaloneClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {

            String directory = "C:\\Workspace\\ProjectMeteor\\src\\java\\com\\meteor\\loader";

            File file = new File(directory);
            URL url = file.toURI().toURL();
            URL[] urls = new URL[]{url};

            ClassLoader cl = new URLClassLoader(urls);

            Class cls = cl.loadClass("com.meteor.loader.ClassToBeLoaded");
            Object o = cls.newInstance();

            System.out.println("Class Loaded: " + o.getClass().toString());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

**Output:-**
Class Loaded: class com.meteor.loader.ClassToBeLoaded

But when I run the same piece of code (in a web application) its throwing ClassNotFoundException.

```
@Path("/test")
public class DynamicWebClass {

    @GET
    @Path("/getFileExplorerNodes")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String getFileExplorerNodes() {
        try {

            String directory = "C:\\Workspace\\ProjectMeteor\\src\\java\\com\\meteor\\loader";

            File file = new File(directory);
            URL url = file.toURI().toURL();
            URL[] urls = new URL[]{url};

            ClassLoader cl = new URLClassLoader(urls);

            Class cls = cl.loadClass("com.meteor.loader.ClassToBeLoaded");
            Object o = cls.newInstance();

            return o.getClass().toString();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "error";
        }
    }

}
```

**Output:-**
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.meteor.loader.ClassToBeLoaded

Why is it throwing exception in web application when it is working fine in standalone program?
How to fix this issue and make it run properly in a web application as well?

Comment: Could you please check that the class is packed in the war

Comment: Yes. The class is there in the war. And the war is present under dist folder of the project.

Comment: But you are pointing to some other directory in C:/. Provide a relative url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like problem with the URL provided to the Class loader. Please provide a relative **URL**

Comment: Thank you very much for the information. Especially for pointing my url to the war. Alternatively, we can replace URLClassLoader with the default one.                                                         **ClassLoader cl = DynamicWebClass.class.getClassLoader();**